# How to apply change from flyspell correction popup in Markdown mode?

Tags: flyspell

This seems like such a dumb question. I'm using spacemacs and have in configuration-layers

```
(spell-checking :variables
                     enable-flyspell-auto-completion t)
```

So I'm in markdown and I pause the cursor on a misspelled word, I get a useful auto-completion box with suggestions. The only problem is, I cannot figure out how to apply the change suggested. tab and return both quit the auto-completion window. What am I missing? I get the expected behaviour in text mode and org mode.